# How to shift entire plot in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have used the following code to generate the graph as shown. My data set is stored in "tot.dos".

```
set autoscale
unset log
unset label
set xtic auto
set ytic auto
set xlabel "X"
set ylabel "Y"
set arrow 1 from 3.44,0 to 3.44,150 nohead ls 10 dt 2 lw 2 lc 'red'
set xrange [-1.5:9]
set yrange [0:150]
plot "tot.dos" using 1:2 w l lw 2 lc 'blue' title 'Total'
pause -1 "Hit any key to continue \n"
```

[image]

In this plot, the point at which "Total" is zero (let's consider it to be the centre of the graph), is approximately x=4. Now, I want to shift this entire plot to the left (along -x direction) so that the new centre of the graph is at x=0. Is there any way I can do it?

I thought adding an extra line *x=x-4* would work, but it didn't. I use Ubuntu 20.04. Also, please ignore the red dashed line, it might be confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understood your question correctly, you want to shift your data by `4` to the left.
So, what about the following which subtracts `4` from all x values?

```
plot "tot.dos" using ($1-4):2
```